# Validate a pattern in java

Tags: java, validation, tokenize

I have to validate following pattern in java

```
X.X.X
```

Where `X` can be any valid integer, but `X.X.X` will be in form of string.

Currently I am tokenizing the string to check for the values and also the number of levels.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: yes, a regular expression. Something like: `"\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) for it.

The regex `"[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+"` should work.

- `\\d` - means a digit.
- the '+' means one or more of the last element.
- `\\.` is a dot.

Code snap:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+").matcher("");
matcher.reset("11.1234.33333");
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
matcher.reset("1.abcd.3");
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Will produce, as expected:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Why have the `\\d` between brackets? It's unnecessary.

Comment: @AntonH Habit, I personally find it more readable - but it is a personal preference and nothing more.

Comment: Just take care that digits are not always ints ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your solution works and is understandable from you and your team, why would you change it?

You can use a regex but it is not fundamentally better. Stick to what works and is simple to you.